# How to download updates made before a time point from remote server by git

Tags: git, git-pull

Git remote server may have many updates for a repo, if I just want to download the updates for this repo, which were made before a time point, what git command should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, in general, no single command for that; it's not how Git was designed to operate.  The general overall design for Git is:

- you get *everything*, then
- you pick out the stuff you like.

Unless there's some high cost to downloading unnecessary extra data, just let that work.  If there is some such high cost, you will need to do work on the server side: create a branch name to identify the latest commit you'd like, then use a limited `git fetch` from the client.  For instance:

```
server$ git branch for-client a123456
```

would create a new branch name `for-client` pointing to commit `a123456`, after which, on the client:

```
client$ git fetch origin for-client
```

would bring down commits up through and including `a123456`, after which you can refer to `a123456` as `origin/for-client`.